# Converting multiple .msg files to PDF

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I am trying to convert multiple Outlook .msg files to a single PDF file so I can store them as a record of correspondence for Project archives.

I am using Outlook 2010 and Adobe XI Pro. When I highlight multiple .msg files, right click and select "Convert to PDF", I only get the first file in the group converted. It's attachments are preserved. How do I get it to include all of the .msg files in the conversion.

I was hoping I would get one large PDF file that had each message bookmarked.

Comment: I have a simple work around.  Convert each email into a .PDF file then merge the .PDF files when you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Print to Adobe PDF instead of convert to PDF as a right-click context menu. All your e-mails should print to one PDF. This works for me in Outlook 2013.